# "Assign" Role Association between two classes

Tags: design, uml, class, system

If there is Class A and Class B and there is an association that B can be assigned to A.And the multiplicity is 1:M or M:1 from A to B.Example:

1.Room has Collection of Keys, and Key can can assigned to Room.

2.Match has a Referee, and Referee can be assigned to Collection of Matches.

I want to know, what would be correct place to put an assign Method?

In example 1, Room should have an assign(RoomKey) Method or RoomKey should have assingToRoom(Room) method?Are both ways correct?

Comment: In an [aggregate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design#aggregate_root).

Comment: In real-world programming, there's no THE correct way to do things, it's not like a school assignment; the whole point is that you are literally making up these representations as you go. You're the one who's studying some real world scenario, or requirements, and formulating the problems (and ideas, conditions, constraints, etc.) in some way that helps you solve them. The only question is if a particular representation satisfies these needs or not (there will be different pros and cons that you have to investigate/try based on your understanding of the problem).

Comment: So my suggestion is to make a small test app and try both, as well as the aggregate approach that Robert Harvey suggested. Check how it would work, get a feel for how the code would be used. Then make the problem a bit more complicated in some way that changes an established assumption (e.g. add a requirement for a master key that can open all the doors, or for a door that requires two keys to be opened), and try to change the code - see what aspects of it help, and what gets in the way. (The point is that different designs support certain kinds of changes better.)

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Why not making this an answer?

Comment: @qwerty_so: I'll consider it, but to me, it feels more like a comment addressed at the OP, and less like a proper, generally useful answer - it's not really addressing the question itself (or if it does, then only tangentially).

Comment: thanks for clarification.These things sometimes create confusion.I hope i will get expertise with time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This requirement

> Room has Collection of Keys

makes

```
room.assignKey(roomKey)
```

a natural piece of code. Although a better name would be `addKey()`.

Given where the collection lives, there are drawbacks to using:

```
roomKey.assignToRoom(room)
```

Because now, for the collection to work `RoomKey` has to turn around and call `room.assignKey(this)`. Which is a little busy, though not evil. But now `RoomKey` has to know `Room` exists.

It was better when only `Room` knew about `RoomKey` and not the other way around as well.  I like to limit what knows about what.  The less things know about other things the more things you can change without breaking things.

Comment: I was referring some resource where in 2-3 cases they were doing the later way mentioned by you,but I was thinking what is wrong with the other way.Anyhow,now i can say that we can have both way and having with room is natural and makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

In an [aggregate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design#aggregate_root) class.

> Example: When you drive a car, you do not have to worry about moving the wheels forward, making the engine combust with spark and fuel, etc.; you are simply driving the car. In this context, the car is an aggregate of several other objects

Answer (score -4):

I don't know the flow of the uml that you made, maybe my answer can help you, if there is a roomkey and there must be a relationship between fields that are the same as the data type, first see if they match, the answer is correct if the referee and the match have a connection

Comment: I did not get what you are trying to say.The relationship is assign,that I have mentioned above.Room class has its own independent attributes and RoomKey has its own independent attributes.Room has collection of RoomKeys.Now what would be correct place to put assign method?Room class or RoomKey class?

Comment: What primary key, if roomkeys, are assigned room class

Comment: I am not talking about DB level details like primary key and all.You can assume room ahs room number as primary key and RoomKey has RoomKeyId as primary key.But those are in DB design.I am at UML level.